# array lists and reading from a file

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

So I've made a multi-dimensional array lists where surnames, forenames, email.. etc should be stored and it reads this information form a .txt file. There seems to be an index out of bounds error popping up and I dont know what for.

```
public static void readFilesIntoArrayLists(String filename) throws IOException
{
Scanner in;
int i = 0;
in = new Scanner(filename);
String [] fileElements;

mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());

while(in.hasNext())
{
  fileElements = (in.nextLine().split(","));
  mainList.get(0).add(fileElements[0]);
  mainList.get(1).add(fileElements[1]);
  mainList.get(2).add(fileElements[2]);
  mainList.get(3).add(fileElements[3]);
  mainList.get(4).add(fileElements[4]);
}
in.close();
System.out.println("Files have been read..");
}
```

Comment: are you sure `fileElements` has at least 5 elements on each line? the error is probably coming from there

Comment: Are you sure that all lines in your file have 5 elements separated by comas, do you have blank lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating a `Scanner` which reads the file contents. Your `Scanner` reads the string from the parameter `filename`.

To fix this, replace the current initialization

```
in = new Scanner(filename);
```

by this:

```
in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename), "UTF-8");
```

Make sure to check whether your file is actually UTF-8 encoded.

You get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, since the `filename` does not match your desired line format.

Just two further remarks:

- You should use the method `hasNextLine` in the while condition, instead of `hasNext`.
- As already pointed out in the other answers, you should handle lines which do not match your expected format.

Answer (score 3):

you are not checking to see if you have lines in the file which miss some of the parameters (or blank lines, or whatever).

your while loop should look something like:

```
while(in.hasNext())
{
  fileElements = (in.nextLine().split(","));
  if (fileElements.length == 5) {
    mainList.get(0).add(fileElements[0]);
    mainList.get(1).add(fileElements[1]);
    mainList.get(2).add(fileElements[2]);
    mainList.get(3).add(fileElements[3]);
    mainList.get(4).add(fileElements[4]);
  } else {
    // do something with error lines - log it, print to screen, or just skip them
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always make sure that the **index** you are trying to access in an `ArrayList` are actually occupied.

A common scenario would be

```
while(in.hasNext())
    {
        fileElements = (in.nextLine().split(","));
        int idx = 0;
        for (; idx < fileElement.size() && idx < 5; idx++ ) {
            mainList.get(idx).add(fileElements[idx]);
        }   

        //And if you need to fill all your five arrays with data, then
        while (idx < 5) {
            mainList.get(idx).add([""]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You didn't solve the problem, you just reversed it. in his code he has the risk of too few elements in a line, in your code - a line with more than five will throw NullPointerException on `mainList.get(index).add()` when index is 5 or more

Answer (score 0):

the code seems correct. fist you must be sure that you have 5 number of elements.

modified code:

```
    String [] fileElements;
    mainList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    mainList.add(new ArrayList<String>());

int length = fileElements.getLength();
    while(in.hasNext())
    {
      fileElements = (in.nextLine().split(","));
for(int index = 0; index < length; index++)
{
      mainList.get(index).add(fileElements[index]);
}
    }
```

Comment: You didn't solve the problem, you just reversed it. in his code he has the risk of too few elements in a line, in your code - a line with more than five will throw NullPointerException on `mainList.get(index)` when index is 5 or more